# Twitter Bootstrap 3 tooltip not working when more data attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 links in my view using Rails helpers and twitter bootstrap tooltip:

```
= link_to download_group_path(group), class: 'btn btn-mini tip-top',
  "data-toggle" => "tooltip", title: 'Download' do
  %i.elusive.el-icon-pencil-alt

= link_to export_group_path(group),
  class: 'btn btn-mini tip-top', "data-toggle" => "tooltip",
  title: 'Export' do
  %i.elusive.el-icon-tasks

= link_to '#', class: 'btn btn-mini tip-top', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', title: 'Delete',
  'data-url' => group_path(group), 'data-selector' => 'delete',
  'data-name' => group.name, 'data-count' => group.users.count  do
  %i.elusive.el-icon-remove-sign
```

"Download" and "Export" work but "Delete" is not working. When I remove the other data attributes it works. For some reason in the HTML "Delete" does not have `data-original-title` as "Download" and "Export"

I'm initializing the tooltips this way: `$('.tip-top').tooltip();`

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `data-selector` item. Per the bootstrap docs:

> If a selector is provided, tooltip objects will be delegated to the specified targets.

Since you're calling the `tooltip()` function on the links themselves, you don't need the `data-selector` field. With your code, when it tries to initialize the third tooltip, it instead looks for `delete` elements within the `a` element; it doesn't find any, so no tooltip is created.

The selector option is for a situation where you might have all of these links in a containing `div`, say `#mydiv`. Then you could add a `'data-selector' => 'a'` to the wrapping `div` and then just call `$('#mydiv').tooltip()`. This would then apply tooltips to all of the `a` elements within the `div`.

Comment: Thank you. The `data-selector` is being used in another stuff, not for the tooltip.